# Azure Devops for Power apps

Tags: azure-devops, powerapps

I am trying to implement devops for Powerapps by referring below link. In manual deployment, usually we will export the app and import on another app by updating it. And then we publish it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/build-tools-overview

But when I add task for import and export, I am getting the error as

> "##[error]Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an
>   empty string."

Anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to check in after the weekend what the status on this issue was? Does the export task can be succeed after you specify the organization name in URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "##[error]Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an
>   empty string."

I saw you shared a debug log in our official community.

After analyze it and decompile the dlls that this task used, I found the issue you faced caused by the compile process has a process `Get-Organizations` to detect your **powerapp organization name**. But, the url you specified in the service connection is `https://xxxx.powerapps.com/` which does not contain the organization name.

The correct format should be `https://{org name}.crm.dynamics.com`. You can check this doc to [discover the URL for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/discover-url-organization-web-api).